# Best way to find objects not present in both lists

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures

I am working on a module that depends on checking if there are any objects not present in either of the 2 lists. The implementation is supposed to be in Python.

Consider the simplified object def:

```
class Foo(object):

  def __init__(self, attr_one=None, attr_two=None):
    self.attr_one = attr_one
    self.attr_two = attr_two

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.attr_one == other.attr_one and self.attr_two == other.attr_two
```

I have two separate lists that can encapsulates multiple instances of class Foo as follows:

```
list1 = [Foo('abc', 2), Foo('bcd', 3), Foo('cde', 4)]
list2 = [Foo('abc', 2), Foo('bcd', 4), Foo('efg', 5)]
```

I need to figure out the objects that are present in one list and absent in the other on the basis of attr_one. In this case, the desired output for items present in first list and missing  in the second list is given below.

```
`['Foo('bcd', 3), Foo('cde', 4)]`
```

Similarly, the items present in list 2 but not in list 1

```
 [Foo('bcd', 4), Foo('efg', 5)]
```

I would like to know if there is a way to match the basis of attr_one as well.

```
  List 1                 List 2        
  Foo('bcd', 3)          Foo('bcd', 4)
  Foo('cde', 4)          None
  None                   Foo('efg', 5)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "on the basis of `attr_one`"; wouldn't the list of items present in the first list and missing in the second, considering only `attr_one`, be just `Foo('cde',4)`, since `list2` has `Foo('bcd',4)`, which matches `attr_one` for `Foo('bcd',3)`?

Comment: Will the lists always be sorted as your example shows?  Are they sortable?

Comment: @nell they can be sorted if required.
Kyle - What I want to do is create a tabular structure of the attributes that vary and the differing value. For example, in the first example, I want to say that "attr_two" is different with the values 3 and 4 in list 1 and list 2 respectively.
In the other examples, there is not equivalent value of "attr_one" in one list that is present in the other, so the value in one of the lists is None.

Answer (score 9):

Since you already have an `__eq__` method defined, You can use list comprehension to find the uniqueness of the objects in either of the lists.

```
print [obj for obj in list1 if obj not in list2]
```

Comment: How would I find the attributes' values that differ slightly from the objects in other lists?

Comment: You can a diff between the __dict__ of the objects in each list.

Answer (score 4):

A good way to quickly compare lists to determine which elements are present in one but not the other is to create sets from the original lists and take the difference between the two sets. In order for the list to be made into a set, the objects it contains must be [hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), so you must define a new `__hash__()` method for your `Foo` objects:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.attr_one,self.attr_two))
```

Note that since tuples are hashable, as long as `attr_one` and `attr_two` are hashable types, this implementation should be pretty solid.

Now, to determine which elements are present in one list but not the other:

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
missing_from_1 = set2 - set1
missing_from_2 = set1 - set2
```

To do this on the basis of only one of the attributes, you can create your sets using only the attributes themselves:

```
set1 = set([i.attr_one for i in list1])
```

Of course, this means that you'll end up with results that only tell you the `attr_one` values that are present in one list but not the other, rather than giving you the actual `Foo` objects. The objects themselves are easy to find, however, once you have the "missing" sets:

```
missing_Foos = set()
for attr in missing_from_2:
    for i in list1:
        if i.attr_one == attr:
            missing_Foos.add(i)
```

This can be rather computationally expensive, though, if you have very long lists.

EDIT: using sets is only really useful if you have extremely large lists and therefore need to take advantage of the computational efficiency of set operations. Otherwise, it may be simpler to simply use list comprehensions, as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I'd do this - either using `sets`, or with `filter`:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, attr_one=None, attr_two=None):
        self.attr_one = attr_one
        self.attr_two = attr_two

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.attr_one == other.attr_one and self.attr_two == other.attr_two

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.attr_one)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Foo {} {}>".format(self.attr_one, self.attr_two)

def main():
    a = Foo('test', 1)
    b = Foo('test', 1)

    list1 = [Foo('abc', 2), Foo('bcd', 3), Foo('cde', 4)]
    list2 = [Foo('abc', 2), Foo('bcd', 4), Foo('efg', 5)]

    # With sets
    list1set = set(list1)
    list2set = set(list2)

    print list1set.intersection(list2set) 
    # Returns set([<Foo abc 2>])

    # With filter
    list2attr_one = [l.attr_one for l in list2]
    print filter(lambda x: x.attr_one in list2attr_one, list1)
    # Returns [<Foo abc 2>, <Foo bcd 3>]
```

Comment: wont set(list1).union(set(list2)) - set(list1).intersection(set(list2)) return me the unique values?